How to add custom http header to graphql mutation using graphqlGradlePlugin?
I use GraphqlGradlePlugin to generate code from graphql schema and send gql mutations to other service.
My goal is to add a custom header with dynamic value. Something like:
x-dayOfWeek-header:Monday.
I tried to check ask AI but didn't have any luck so far.
